# Powershell: Output a search from a csv to a small gui

Tags: powershell

maybe one of you experts can help a complete newbie (I don't know if what I want is even feasible).
Let's assume I have a CSV file with various data. (see csv_screenshot)[csv_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ux2WT.png)

I import this data via Powershell into a small GUI . How can I make it so that when I search for "Paris", I really only get the output for Paris in the GUI as a list view like this (see powershell_screenshot)

[powershell_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhpBk.png)

Currently the output in the GUI looks like this (see current_result.png). How do I get it nicely formatted as a list in there. I really want to insert it like this (via Out Grid View it is no problem)
[current_result.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSwCy.png)

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles();

function search_csv {
    $Input = $textbox_Search.text
    $Input = "*$Input*"
    $Input_Result  = import-csv -path C:\Users\check.csv -Header "Location", "Client", "Mobile Device" 
    $output_TextBox.text = $Input_Result -like $Input 
   
  
}

$search_csvtool = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $search_csvtool.Text = "CSV Search"
    $search_csvtool.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(674,500)
    $search_csvtool.FormBorderStyle ="FixedDialog"
    $search_csvtool.TopMost = $true
    $search_csvtool.MaximizeBox = $false
    $search_csvtool.MinimizeBox = $true
    $search_csvtool.ControlBox = $true
    $search_csvtool.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
    $search_csvtool.Font = "Courier New"

$label_Search = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label_Search.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(195,18)
    $label_Search.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(265,32)
    $label_Search.TextAlign ="MiddleCenter"
    $label_Search.Text = "Please enter "
    $search_csvtool.Controls.Add($label_Search)

$textbox_Search = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $textbox_Search.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(195,50)
    $textbox_Search.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(266,37)
    $search_csvtool.Controls.Add($textbox_Search)

$button_Search = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $button_Search.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(195,80)
    $button_Search.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(266,24)
    $button_Search.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
    $button_Search.Text = "Search"
    $button_Search.Add_Click({search_csv})
    $search_csvtool.Controls.Add($button_Search)

$output_TextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $output_TextBox.Multiline = $true;
    $output_TextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(16,130)
    $output_TextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(627,314)
    $output_TextBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
    $output_TextBox.ReadOnly = $true;
    $search_csvtool.Controls.Add($output_TextBox)

    $search_csvtool.Add_Shown({$search_csvtool.Activate()})
    [void] $search_csvtool.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: I guess you're looking to format your result using `| Format-List | Out-String`. **Tip 1**: do NOT use a variable name `$Input` because that is an [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#input). Choose another name for that. **Tip 2**: Import the CSV only once in your code, not every time the function search_csv is called upon. **Tip 3**: Use `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms` instead of the ancient `LoadWithPartialName()` method

Comment: Thanks first of all for the tips. I have incorporated your tips. I had already tested Format-List | Out-String before. Same result. The output in the GUI is still not formatted as a list (see current_result.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here's what I meant in my comment:

Start the code with

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$csvData = Import-Csv -path 'C:\Users\check.csv' -Header "Location", "Client", "Mobile Device" 

function search_csv {
    $searchThis = $textbox_Search.Text.Trim()
    # use $script: scoping here to reference the $csvData variable
    $data = $script:csvData | Where-Object {$_.Location -like "*$searchThis*"}
    if ($data) {
        $output_TextBox.Text = ($data | Format-List | Out-String).Trim()
    }
    else {
        $output_TextBox.Text = "Not found.."
    }
}
```

Then create the rest of the form as you did.
Important: Destroy the form when done with a last new code line:

```
$search_csvtool.Dispose()
```

You should then have this result:

[image]

---

As per your comment to empty the textbox when nothing (or just whitespace) has been entered, you *could* change the function to:

```
function search_csv {
    $searchThis = $textbox_Search.Text.Trim()
    # use $script: scoping here to reference the $csvData variable
    $data = $script:csvData | Where-Object {$_.Location -like "*$searchThis*"}
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($searchThis)) {
        $output_TextBox.Clear()
    }
    elseif ($data) {
        $output_TextBox.Text = ($data | Format-List | Out-String).Trim()
    }
    else {
        $output_TextBox.Text = "Not found.."
    }
}
```

However, as [postanote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73837660/powershell-output-a-search-from-a-csv-to-a-small-gui/73838325?noredirect=1#comment130388182_73838325) already commented, it would be much better to simply disable the search button and only enable it when something other that whitespace has been entered.

To do that, you need to add an eventhandler to the textbox:

```
$textbox_Search = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textbox_Search.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(195,50)
$textbox_Search.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(266,37)
$textbox_Search.Add_TextChanged({
    # enable the button when there is at least one non-whitespace character present
    $button_Search.Enabled = $this.Text -match '\S'
    # or use
    # $button_Search.Enabled = (-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($this.Text))
})
$search_csvtool.Controls.Add($textbox_Search)
```

And initialize the button to be **disabled** at startup:

```
$button_Search = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button_Search.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(195,80)
$button_Search.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(266,24)
$button_Search.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
$button_Search.Text = "Search"
# initialize to Disabled; will be enabled as soon as there is text entered in the $textbox_Search
$button_Search.Enabled = $false  
$button_Search.Add_Click({search_csv})
$search_csvtool.Controls.Add($button_Search)
```

<sup>Inside an event handler, you can refer to the object itself using automatic variable `$this`</sup>

Comment: Oh my god one small step for Theo, one giant for me. i confess, i wouldn't have thought of it. That motivates me all the more to keep at it. I have entered another condition via -or. Thanks for the help and inspiration! 

Encore: Do you have a hint for me, what I can do so that the output remains empty, if I do not enter a search term and press the button?

Comment: @DaRockwilda83 sure, only I'm on mobile now so maybe later or tomorrow

Comment: As for this ***Do you have a hint for me, what I can do so that the output remains empty if I do not enter a search term and press the button?*** Just use conditional logic (if/the or try catch or -match, etc...) to check for $null and process however you like. Though not really sure why anyone would intentionally ask for a result when a question was never asked. Meaning that is the same thing as not putting search criteria in.  ***From a pure GUI perspective, ideally, that search button should not even be active until something is entered in the search box***, to avoid confusion altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to go thru your string output line by line and change this.

That stated, you probably won't like how it looks.  Normalized colons will probably look better.

This code should do the trick.  I'll let you be the judge of if it looks "better"

```
$dataLines = ($data | Format-List | Out-String).Trim() -split '(?>\r\n|\n)'
$dataText = @(
   foreach ($dataLine in $dataLines) {
      $dataLine -replace '\s{1,}\:', ':'
   }
) -join [Environment]::Newline
$output_TextBox.Text = $dataText
```